# how to call same either document ready or id onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, document-ready

this is a ajax  call sending while page loading

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      strCourseCat = $('#strCourseCat').val();
      var strengthsData = '';
      $.ajax({
      success: function (response) {},
      error: function (request, status, error) {}
      });
  });
```

Similarly i want to send the same call when i click on this id `#opportunityTab`:

```
$("#opportunityTab").click(function(){

});
```

How can i do that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a function. You may wanna move the `click` event and the `callAjax()` function in the `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    strCourseCat = $('#strCourseCat').val();
    var strengthsData = '';

    // Ajax function
    function callAjax() {
        $.ajax({
          success: function (response) {},
          error: function (request, status, error) {}
        });
    }

    // Click to call ajax function
    $("#opportunityTab").click(function(){
        callAjax();
    });

    callAjax();
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError:   `callAjax` is not defined

Comment: This might be a problem because of the document.ready. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can call the same function on Click handler like below.

```
$("#opportunityTab").click(function(){
      strCourseCat = $('#strCourseCat').val();
      var strengthsData = '';
      $.ajax({
      success: function (response) {},
      error: function (request, status, error) {}
      });
});
```

Or you can define a function for reusability.

```
function SendAjax()
{
          strCourseCat = $('#strCourseCat').val();
          var strengthsData = '';
          $.ajax({
          success: function (response) {},
          error: function (request, status, error) {}
          });
}
```

and reuse it like

```
$("#opportunityTab").click(function(){
          SendAjax();
});
```